# Refresh the whole page without reloading it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

I was trying to refresh the whole page without reloading it. I've tried some jQuery code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#tablet2').load(document.URL +' #tablet2');
    $('#tablet1').load(document.URL +' #tablet1');
    $('#StateIntegrity').load(document.URL +' #StateIntegrity');
    //$('#modalRef').load(document.URL +' #modalRef');

}, 30000);
```

But this is only refreshing some divs like: `tablet2`, `tablet1`, `espStateIntegrity`, and not the whole page.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: If you want to do the whole page, remove the selectors after the URLs and make one call to reload the `body`. Also note that polling the server for changes every 30 seconds isn't a great idea. I'd suggest looking in to WebSockets or Server Sent Events if you want to keep the client UI in sync with server side data

Comment: how is that possible ? i cant do  $('#tablet2').load(document.URL');

Comment: It depends on what server side technology you're using, but 20 seconds in Google should give you a good start.

Comment: i will look into that thankx

Comment: If you mean how can you do the load, then just `$('body').load(document.URL + ' body');` but as I mentioned in my first comment, I would strongly suggest you *don't* do this in a production system.

Comment: when i try $('body').load(document.URL + ' body'); i just lose the page content after the refresh

Comment: location.reload(); ? :)